# Converting hex string 2 chars at a time

Tags: javascript

I'm reading through some JavaScript code that parses a hex string into a buffer, like so:

```
function bufferFromHexString(string)
{
    var buffer = new Buffer(string.length/2);

    for (var i=0; i<string.length/2; i++)
    {
        buffer.writeInt8( parseInt(input.substr(i*2,2), 16), i );
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

But I'm not sure why this is taking two characters at a time, rather than one. Can anyone explain  this?

Comment: Why it has to, or how it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes two hex characters to make an eight-bit (one-byte) integer. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

One byte (eight bits) has `2^8=256` possible values.

To represent 256 in hexadecimal you need two digits (e.g. `0xff = 255d`).

```
00 = 0
01 = 1
02 = 2
...
fd = 253
fe = 254
ff = 255
```